# xul overlay for new menu in TB/Firefox main menubar

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, overlay, xul

I'd like to add a new menu at the end of the main menu bar (file, edit, ...) after the Help menu via an extension i wrote.
I already know how to add a new item to one of the menus by something like:

```
<menupopup id="menu_HelpPopup">
   <menuitem id="example-item" oncommand="alert('Hello!');" label="TEST" accesskey="i"/>
</menupopup>
```

But I didn't get it to work like I explained above.(btw, Where can I look up the id of the menu bar?). this is what i tried so far.

```
<menubar id="????">
  <menu id="test-menu" label="TEST"
    accesskey="d">
    <menuitem id="example-item2" oncommand="alert('Hello!');" label="TEST" accesskey="i"/>
  </menu>
</menubar>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need the menubar id, which is `main-menubar` and also your missing the menupopup.  I have not tested, but this looks right to me:

```
<menubar id="main-menubar">
    <menu id="test-menu" label="TEST"
    accesskey="d">
        <menupopup id="test-popup">
            <menuitem id="example-item2" oncommand="alert('Hello!');" label="TEST" accesskey="i"/>
        </menupopup>
    </menu>
</menubar>
```

If your trying to find the id of things like the `#main-menubar` I recommend DOM inspector.